# Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1})=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Got stuck in the middle of proving a limit and I don't know what to do.

Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1})=0$

I wrote the equation as $\Rightarrow(\sqrt{n^2+2021}+\sqrt{n^2+1})\,\frac{({\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1}})}{\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

=$\frac{(n^2+2021)-(n^2+1)}{\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1}} = \frac{2020}{\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

and now I'm stuck , I don't know exactly how to proceed.

Any hints?
Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: You started with $\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1}$. That is not the same as $(\sqrt{n^2+2021}+\sqrt{n^2+1}) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1}}$. What you really wanted to do was to multiply the original expression by $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+2021}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+2021}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$. That would yield $\frac{2020}{\sqrt{n^2+2021}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$. This clearly tends towards $0$ when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Initially, you should have  `+` in the denominator.

Comment: But we have Absolute value , doesn't it change to + ? by the definition |$a_n-L$|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} [\sqrt{n^2+2021}-\sqrt{n^2+1}] =\lim_{n\to \infty} n[(1+2021/n^2)^{1/2}-(1+1/n^2)^{1/2}$$
Use $(1+z)^k =1+k$ if $|z|<<1$.
Then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n[1+2021/(2n^2)-1-1/(2n^2)]= \lim_{n \to \infty} 1010/n=0$$